# Not able to move .txt files to archive folder in java

Tags: java

I need to move all files ending with .txt to the archive folder.

I have the below code, but the `if (sourcepath.endsWith(".txt"))` doesn't validate the file extension.

```
      File directory = new File("Archive");
      System.out.println((System.getProperty("user.dir")));
      File directory1 = new File (System.getProperty("user.dir"));
      File[] files = directory1.listFiles();
      if (! directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
            for(File f : files ) {
                   Path sourcePath = Paths.get(f.getName());
                   System.out.println(sourcePath);
                   if (sourcePath.endsWith(".txt")){   // Not validating
                       System.out.println(sourcePath.endsWith(extension));
                       Files.move(sourcePath, Paths.get("Archive"));
                   }
            }
            System.out.println("Clearing Folder.....All Files moved to Archive Directory");
      }
```

Expected Output:

```
C:\Users\harsshah\workspace\FFPreBatchValidation
.classpath
.project
.settings
bin
kjnk.txt
src
```

kjnk.txt should be moved to Archive folder

Comment: What's the name of the files in your folder ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Javadoc on Path.endsWith(String)? I'll quote: `On UNIX for example, the path"foo/bar" ends with "foo/bar" and "bar". It does not end with "r" or "/bar"` - thus `whatever.txt` won't "end with" `.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [doc about Path.endsWith(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-)

> Tests if this path ends with a Path, constructed by converting the given path string, in exactly the manner specified by the endsWith(Path) method. On UNIX for example, the path "foo/bar" ends with "foo/bar" and "bar". It does not end with "r" or "/bar". Note that trailing separators are not taken into account, and so invoking this method on the Path"foo/bar" with the String "bar/" returns true.

The important part is : `It does not end with "r" or "/bar"`

You must convert the `Path` to a `String` and call `String.endsWith(String)` instead of `Path.endsWith(String)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i > 0) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```

Assuming that you're dealing with simple Windows-like file names, not something like archive.tar.gz.

Btw, for the case that a directory may have a '.', but the filename itself doesn't (like /path/to.a/file), you can do

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
int p = Math.max(fileName.lastIndexOf('/'), fileName.lastIndexOf('\\'));

if (i > p) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
```